# What does ?? () in segfault error mean?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to write an echo server in C (to be honest I'm just copying the code from http://gnosis.cx/publish/programming/sockets.html). Anyhow, compiling the program is no problem but when running it segfaults. gdb gives following error message:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0xb7e46d5c in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

My question is: What does the "??" mean? As I understand it that is where the name the function that failed should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try running 'bt' command it will give the stacktrace. The segfault is most probably in your code which is being notified at libc.so.6. Since libc.so.6 is optimized binary it doesnt have debug symbols so you get ?s.

Answer (score 0):

There are no debug information available in your glibc (since it's usually compiled without debug information). So the only thing you can see is the address of the function - but not its name, because it's not known.

However, you can compile your program with debug information (gcc option: `-ggdb`). Then you can use a debugger like gdb or valgrind to see which line in *your* code caused the segfault.